# ANT build error -- <not> tag not supported

Tags: java, ant, build

One of my build scripts gives me the following error :-

> if doesn't support the nested "not" element

I'm concerned that the version of ant im using does not support `<not>`. From which version upward is the `<not>` tag supported in ANT?

Comment: How about posting the section of the build script that fails and the line number associated with your error message ?

Comment: Sure, @gareth_bowles It would be something like https://gist.github.com/ef283d6b90ae7e54b8f9

Comment: What ant version and ant-contrib version are you using? If you could paste the code directly into the question, it would be more comfortable.

Answer (score 2):

`<not>` only works in selectors, it is not part of the `<if>` tag. You can replace this by using the `<else>` expression.

```
<if>
  <equals arg1="something" arg2="orother">
  <else>
    the stuff you want to do...
  </else>
</if>
```

Comment: Any condition is part of `if` tag, at least documentation says so. And on my installation `not` works as expected.

Answer (score 0):

`<not>` is in Ant since 1.4, see [the source code](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/ant/core/trunk/src/main/org/apache/tools/ant/taskdefs/condition/Not.java?view=markup). Ant-contrib requires 1.5, so theoretically you shouldn't see this issue.

Chances are your `if` task comes from another package, not `ant-contrib`. There must be some other `taskdef` entries in your build file. Or it is not a regular ant distribution.